# Kinect 2 hand detection with Candescent NUI

Tags: image, image-processing, kinect, nui

someone know if the new kinect, have support for Candescent NUI?
I want detect fingers and hands with Candescent, but I can't find if the new OPENNI, kinect, NITE or microsoft SDK have support for the new kinect, accepted too work with Candescent NUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a porting for Candescent NUI to Kinect V2 [here](https://github.com/VentaApps/Candescent-NUI-20148-for-Kinect-V2) but you have to setup your Dependencies to run coorectly, you need OpenNI.net.dll, OpenNI64.dll, XnVNITE.net.dll and Microsoft.Kinect.dll (Kinect SDK V2 dll)

Comment: where can I find this files?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that nobody ported Candescent NUI to Kinect v2.
You can do it by yourself.
His code is pretty good and clear.
A number of months ago I really wanted to port this code to Kinect v2, even started working on that, but realized that I don't want front face finger tracking, but top-down, something more similar to RetroDepth (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96CZ_QPBx0s), and now I am implementing this.

If you only need a finger tracking, similar to Leap Motion, you may use Nimble SDK, it works pretty well (not perfectly) with Kinect v2, in front facing mode, like Candescent does, but it gives use full 3d hand skeleton. With Kinect v1 it works using top-down setup. But I am not sure if they still provide free licenses. Check it.

If they don't provide free license, you can either re-implement Candescent hand tracking features, moreover you could do it more robust, so it could support another depth cameras with different range (near, far) and different resolutions, actually one of the most annoying things (in my opinion) that Candescent has, it's hard coded resolution of depth and color images.

Moreover on the CHI2015 (http://chi2015.acm.org/) will be presented a new technique for hand tracking for Kinect v2 by Microsoft (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-xXrMpOHyc), maybe they will integrate it soon into Kinect SDK v2. Also probably after the conference, its paper will be published and uploaded to acm.org or even to some public library, so you could see how they have done it, and fortunately somebody will implement it soon as well.